# AWS CloudFormation Error 'Value of property AlarmActions must be of type List of String'

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, devops

i am trying to update my cf stack and encounter the following error on deploy:
'Value of property AlarmActions must be of type List of String'

this is the property AlarmActions:

```
 AlarmActions:
                - !Ref SparksTeamSNSTopic
                - !If
                    - CreateProdResources
                    - - !Ref SparksProdAlarmSNSTopic
                      - !ImportValue
                          'Fn::Sub': '${Environment}-BMCMajorAlarmTopic'
                    - - !Ref 'AWS::NoValue'
```

Comment: Your `!If` syntax is incorrect, can you please explain what is expected result out of `!If`?

Comment: yes i can. i want that when i am creating prod reasources the SparksProdAlarmSNSTopic and ${Environment}-BMCMajorAlarmTopic will be added.otherwise ref nothing

Answer (score 0):

As per the AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cw-alarm.html#cfn-cloudwatch-alarms-alarmactions), `AlarmActions` property must contain values, as a list of strings.  So you should have something like this if it's **JSON**:

```
"AlarmActions":[
      {"Ref":"ARN of something"},
      {"Ref":"ARN of something"}           
]
```

But since you've used YAML you should be having something like this:

```
AlarmActions:
      - !Split [",", !Ref SparksTeamSNSTopic]  <-- make sure SparksTeamSNSTopic contains a list of strings; hence this will split it by comma
```

You may define the `SparksTeamSNSTopic` as

```
"SparksTeamSNSTopic" : ["topicarn1", "topicarn2"]
```

Comment: my topic defined correctly. it worked fine before... this was my previous:          AlarmActions:
                - !Ref SparksTeamSNSTopic
                - !If
                    - CreateProdResources
                    - !Ref SparksProdAlarmSNSTopic
                    - !ImportValue
                        'Fn::Sub': '${Environment}-BMCCriticalAlarmTopic'

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
AlarmActions:
    - !Ref SparksTeamSNSTopic
    - !If
      - CreateProdResources
      - - !Ref SparksProdAlarmSNSTopic
        - !ImportValue
            'Fn::Sub': '${Environment}-BMCMajorAlarmTopic'
      - !Ref 'AWS::NoValue'
```

Comment: i will try it. just for my knowlage, it is not possible to refer a list of strings when condition is not met?

Comment: You can, but not with NoValue.

Comment: what is the problem with it?

Comment: `AWS::NoValue` is like `None`.